# Como comparar una consulta y verificar que esta dentro de las fechas limites MySQL?

Tags: php, web, msql

Tengo una pregunta y es la siguiente, yo tengo una base de datos llama recuperacionSolicitadas con estas filas:

email = varchar de 300 de longitud.

token = varchar de 99 de lonitud.

fecha = current_date()

hora = current_time()
He pensado dos formas de hacer una sistema de recuperación que con una vida util:

Idea1:
Esta base de datos la uso para poder hacer un sistema de recuperación de pass seguro con php, a la hora de que el usuario solicita una recuperación(hago 2 seet cookie, uno contiene el email, el otro el token y con un tiempo de vida de 2 horas) lo que se hace es ir a la base de datos con una consulta el email y token. Y no se como hacer que me compare la fecha del token para básicamente sabe si se ha pasado del limite que tiene para poder recuperar las pass.

Idea2:
A la hora de solicitar lo que quiero hacer es que al crear el registro, pues que ese registro luego de 2 horas se auto borré.

Alguien me podrirá ayudar con las consultas ya que no se como hacerlas.Gracias!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Creo que lo que buscas es esto, te lo resumo.

Haz un select y guarda el timestamp que marca el tiempo en que fue solicitado el email de recuperación de contraseña, en una variable php. En este caso yo la llamare $Time, una vez hecho esto, solo tienes que comparar el tiempo de la solicitud con el tiempo actual menos dos horas. Se haría de la siguiente manera:

```
<?
if(strtotime($Time) < strtotime("-2 hours")){ Han pasado mas de dos horas. }
?>
```

Espero que te sirva de ayuda, un saludo!